# having trouble in redirection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, redirect, jquery-dialog

This is strange but i got error while having # at the end of url in browser.

My url is `http://example.com/service_offers/view/3` but when i have  `http://example.com/service_offers/view/3#` this effects url redirection.

I am using jquery ui dialog box and when user close dialog box i have redirection code to the same page from where user has opened it, but problem is that when i have `#` at end of url then redirection getting fail.

And no error is being shown in firebug.I dont know why, Can anyone tell me what is wrong.

jQuery Code is as below

```
$( "#rate_success" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "slide",
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    hide: "fold",
    closeOnEscape: false,
    close : function()
    {
        window.location = window.location.href;
        return false;
    },
    buttons:
    {   
        "Close": function()
        {
            window.location = window.location.href;
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

I am opening this dialog from this `http://example.com/service_offers/view/3`  page. Now if i have `#` at the end of this page link then whole redirection getting fail.

Comment: You should include that code in the question.

Comment: Any reason why you are'nt simply doing a `window.location.reload();`

Comment: @adeneo i have already did that but that redirect me to the error page...May be because of i am using cakephp so it may have some other internal routing issue